# How to change the timezone of the received data to AET in XCRUD?

Tags: php

I've used XCRUD to retrieve the data from my database but I'm facing an issue with the timezone.

```
public static $db_time_zone = '+10:00';
```

I tried setting the default timezone 
    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');

I didn't find any other answer in the XCRUD documentation to support if this is correct or not?

I need to set the timezone in the database as UTC but during displaying of the data on the page I need to change the timezone to AET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but hope this helps if you haven't figured it out already.

The xcrud library will use your server's default timezone (`xcrud.php` @ line 16). If your server's timezone is UTC, which is what you want, you shouldn't change anything.

To display a date value with your desired timezone, simply use a callback to xcrud's `functions.php`.

```
$xcrud->column_callback('date_field', 'display_aet_timezone');
```

And for your callback function:

```
/**
 * Callback to display the time in AET timezone
 */
function display_aet_timezone($value, $fieldname, $primary_key, $row, $xcrud)
{
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Australia/Brisbane'));
    $dt->setTimestamp(strtotime($value));

    return $dt->format('F j, Y @ G:i');
}
```